# GWT execution / rendering of OpenX ad invocation tags

Tags: gwt, render, openx

A bit confounded here, coming up dry on Google, and yet afraid some simple answer is right under my nose:  What is/are the best way/ways to get a GWT control to render an OpenX invocation tag?  I've tried placing either OpenX's "JavaScript" or "iFrame" invocation types (for a zone) within GWT InnerHTML or HTML tags using UiBinder, and it's a no go.  Do I need to get some eval()-ish execution of this OpenX invocation code happening?  Just stuck, and any suggestions/brief example would be appreciated. (Note: Use of UiBinder layout not a requirement... Happy to switch back to programmatic syntax.). Thank you so much.

Comment: I have no idea what OpenX is and I am sure many others are in the same boat. It would be helpful to get a good answer that you provided some code you already have or at least a snippet of what you are trying to insert into the DOM and what do you mean when it's a "no go", does the app crash/not compile/not do what you want?

Comment: Strelok, thank you, points well taken.  Aside, here's short definition of OpenX I've pasted from a site called Adserverplugins.com:  "To the comment above, OpenX is (to quote aderverplugins.com) "OpenX Ad Server is an ad server, created and published by the British-American company OpenX.org. It is a system that can be used to manage and optimize the advertising space on one or more websites."

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use an InlineHTML control in UiBinder, and declare it as a named ui:field.  In code, referencing that ui:field, I first set a string to the "IFrame"-style invocation tag for the ad, as provided by OpenX, and after adding some random numbers to it (to head off browser-cacheing), I then apply the .setHTML(openx_iframe_invocation_tag_string) method to the reference, and the ad shows up in the space designated for the InnerHTML control.

As regards executing a JavaScript-style tag, some may want to try (I myself didn't go to far with it), execution of it within GWT via something like this script eval technique shown on http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7052.